# Rails nested form ignoring validations conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms

I have this simple setup: an Account `#has_one` Owner of the class Person.

Now the form for the account creating and update uses a nested form for the person's attributes - such as name, e-mail and password.

There are validations for these attributes - password requires confirmation, e-mail can't be blank, etc.

But some validations has conditions using `:if`.

For instance, I only requires the presence of a password if the `password_digest` attribute is blank, so:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :if => :requires_password?

def requires_password?
  password_digest.blank?
end
```

**The thing is:** it's bypassing the condition, like ignoring it completely, BUT **only** when using the nested form mentioned above.

If I test it using a direct form to the Person class it works, the validations take in consideration their conditions.

What is happening ?

I'm using Rails 4.1.0.beta1.

**Update.** Just found out that it's nothing to do with the validations, but with the fact that it only happens on #update. When rendering the nested form, it tries to create a new one instead of updating the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behaviour of has_one relationships in ActiveRecord. You should add the `validate: true` attribute and value to the `has_one` relationship

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :owner, class_name: 'Person', validate: true, unless: :password_digest?
end
```

Have a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. The validation does WORK, the problem is that the condition (`:if` option) is being ignored. Are you suggesting that `validate: true` will fix this ? Another thing, the class that use `has_one` is the Person, but the form is the other way around, it's for an Account with a Person nested in it. In other words, the nested form is for the `belongs_to` relation.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. From the Rails API:

> **:update_only**
>
> For a one-to-one association, this option allows you to specify how nested attributes are to be used when an associated record already exists. In general, an existing record may either be updated with the new set of attribute values or be replaced by a wholly new record containing those values. By default the :update_only option is false and the nested attributes are used to update the existing record only if they include the record's :id value. Otherwise a new record will be instantiated and used to replace the existing one. However if the :update_only option is true, the nested attributes are used to update the record's attributes always, regardless of whether the :id is present. The option is ignored for collection associations.

That's it.